# Drawing the circles of a dev express radar chart

Tags: c#, charts, devexpress

I have a XtraReports.UI.XRChart control and i've set up all the necesary options to function.. but i cant draw alternating circle colors on the radar.. there is an example only its not the circles that alternate ( link : http://demos.devexpress.com/XtraChartsDemos/CustomDraw/RadarDiagramToPoint.aspx )

Eny ideea what options or properties i should use?

// Solution

RadarDiagram myDiagram = (RadarDiagram)xrChart1.Diagram;
myDiagram.AxisY.Interlaced = true;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw that you answered in your post with:

RadarDiagram myDiagram = (RadarDiagram)xrChart1.Diagram; myDiagram.AxisY.Interlaced = true;

that is absolutely correct.

If you could, would you mark this answer as correct so that the issue shows as answered on stack overflow?

Also in the future if something comes up, feel free to contact me as I'm the Charting Evangelist for DevExpress and would appreciate any feedback you have to give!

Comment: Ok, tx for your feedback. I'll keep your advice under consideration when in need of charting help :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know this control but you can try to use the Paint event and draw over the graphic anything you want.. :)

If the control does not have it, you can make a derivate class and override the paint method.